# C# Cant bind List to DataGridView -

Tags: c#, list, datagridview, bind

I must be going mad - I can't seem to do the simple task of making my list display in my DataGridView by using the dgv.datasource = list code.  No errors appear but my list remains blank - can anyone help i'm sure its something obvious but I just can't spot it.

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApp4
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<DGVNames> NamesList = new List<DGVNames>();

            NamesList.Add(new DGVNames("Adam", 18, "Wigan"));
            NamesList.Add(new DGVNames("Bob", 21, "Bolton"));

            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = NamesList;

        }
        }

}
```

and this is my class..

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp4
{
    class DGVNames
    {
        public String strName;
        public int intAge;
        public String strTown;

        public DGVNames(String _strName, int _intAge, String _strTown)
        {
            strName = _strName;
            intAge = _intAge;
            strTown = _strTown;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Databinding requires *Properties* not mere fields

Comment: could you explain further please? New to C# from VB

Comment: It is no different than VB - it is a NET thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is what New Contributor said - `DataGridView` requires properties to bind to, not just fields. You need `Getters` and `Setters` to get the binding to work.

Try this changing your class to this and it should work:

```
public String strName { get; set; }
public int intAge { get; set; }
public String strTown { get; set; }

public DGVNames(String _strName, int _intAge, String _strTown)
{
    strName = _strName;
    intAge = _intAge;
    strTown = _strTown;
}
```

Comment: Btw, this is also works without setter if OP need readonly property.

Comment: thats it thanks Guys - in my rush for a quick solution I hadn't bothered using Get and Set - Laziness cost me a few hours!

Comment: @Luthfay Nice catch. Didn't know that!